# Files generated by collectstatic not being served in Django

Tags: python, css, django, django-staticfiles

I have a bunch of css/js files being processed with collectstatic. They are succesfully created in my staticfiles directory with numbers appended to them.

```
(env)zain@gandalf ~/projects/xxx[master*]$ ls staticfiles/css/
agreements.6cb653c1aa93.css
```

In my templates, I use {% load static from staticfiles %} and load static assets using the static tag. However, the files generated by collectstatic are not inserted -- rather the files simply in my static folder are used.

I would appreciate any thoughts on how to serve the agreements.6cb653c1aa93.css file in staticfiles instead of agreements.css static.

settings/base.py

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)), '../')
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

Thank you!

EDIT - I am using whitenoise: http://whitenoise.readthedocs.org/en/latest/django.html#add-gzip-and-caching-support

Comment: I think i haven´t used that templatetag so far...
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/#configuring-static-files.
Also, django´s runserver will use your static folder by default instead of staticfiles, which is the location where django sends files for production (so you have to configure something like nginx to serve them).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had debug set to True. This solves it. The only problem remaining is that its not using Gzip, and I am using whitenoise: http://whitenoise.readthedocs.org/en/latest/django.html#add-gzip-and-caching-support

Comment: Are you sure it's not using gzip? How are you checking for this?

Answer (score 0):

In production, Django doesn't serve the files itself. You need to use your web server (Apache, nginx,...) for that.

Refer to the documentation for an example comfiguration: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#serving-files